# character string in file name inside module

Tags: string-manipulation, scoping

I have a module in which at the end a table is exported. That works well. Now I want to use that module such that I can transfer a part of a file name as an argument, such as

```
sig[costmin_, costmax_, name_] :=
Module[{},
now table sigma1 is calculated, then exported
Export["file.name.txt", sigma1, "Table"]
```

The filename of the export file should have the name file.name.txt where 'name' is one of the input arguments to the module so that different results for different input parameters costmin and costmax can be written to different files. How do I do this. As written above it does not work.

Comment: I have found an easier solution:

     'Export[
     StringJoin[{"neutrino.EprimeCostplaneXS.", ToString[name], 
     ".txt"}], sigma1, "Table"
     ]'

Comment: StringJoin + ToString is exactly the solution in linked topic. What do you mean by 'easier'?

Comment: StringJoin makes it easier

Comment: StringJoin makes it easier than StringJoin?